# Random backslashes (Python)

Tags: python, import

I'm tring to open a file using the following code:

```
f=open('C:\Users\gabor\Desktop\NPI\test.csv', 'r')
reader=csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Its returning an error:

```
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'C:\\Users\\gabor\\Desktop\\NPI\test.csv'
```

I've change 'rb' to 'r' and left it out and I keep getting the same error.

Any suggestions on how to open the file?

Comment: That's not the problem, it's just how Python displays literal backslashes. The problem is the last one *isn't* doubled, it is a tab...

Comment: Python is producing a **representation** of your string object, one that can be used to re-create the same value, safely. Backslashes have special meaning in Python string literals, and doubling them escapes them preventing them from being used as escape sequences.

Comment: In other words, you need to worry about the place where there is **not** a double backslash, because that's an escape sequence. `\t` is a tab.

Comment: [Why do backslashes appear twice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24085680/2301450)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need double back-slash in your path.  Or  you can put "r" before the string as:
`f=open(r'C:\Users\gabor\Desktop\NPI\test.csv', 'r')`.

Comment: that cleared the initial error but raised a new one: Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline m