# Extract text with spaces followed by string or end of line

Tags: python, regex

Using regex, I need to get the expected ouput:

```
string="Tue Apr 24 22:35:48 2018 53/e33 
hello:55|Wordcap|abc|abc generate|6|Wordcapdata_proto_req=WINTER Wordcapdata_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5 WordcapTotal_reject=56 WordcapAddition_sum=TEA CUP ONE"

Expected output = ['data_proto_req=WINTER', 'data_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5', 'Total_reject=56', 'Addition_sum=TEA CUP ONE']
```

The problem is dealing with the spaces in these strings : `summer 2.4.5` or `TEA CUP ONE`

This is my intial attempt at getting the regex:

```
print re.findall(r'[W]*ordcap([^|].*?=.*?)[\s|\t]*(?:W|$)', string)
```

The output I'm getting is :

```
['data_proto_req=', 'data_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5', 'Total_reject=56', 'Addition_sum=TEA CUP ONE']
```

Comment: Try [`r'\bWordcap([^|=]*?=[^|]*?)(?=Wordcap|$)'`](https://regex101.com/r/zGs5rA/2)

Comment: @cdarke That `W*` is used because the `(?:W|$)` is consuming the `W` in the next match. Actually, that is why I suggest a lookahead here.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew
It almost worked, thanks for sharing. 
Modified it to : 
r'\bWordcap([^|]*?=.*?)\s*(?=Wordcap|$)'

and now its working. 

I wonder what this does (?=) instead of (?:)

Comment: It is a positive lookahead. It does not consume chars, so there is no need making `W` optional. I added the information to [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50016565/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `(?:W|$)` is consuming the `W` in the next match and thus you used `[W]*`. Actually, this is the case where [**lookarounds**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should be used since they do not consume text, just check if there is a match or not without putting the matched text into the match value.

You may use

```
\bWordcap([^|=]*=.*?)(?=\s*\bWordcap|$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zGs5rA/4)

**Details**

- `\bWordcap` - a word boundary followed with `Wordcap`
- `([^|=]*=[^|]*?)` - Group 1:

  - `[^|=]*` - any 0+ chars other than `|` and `=`, as many as possible
  - `=` - an `=` sign
  - `.*?` -  any 0+ chars other than a newline, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\bWordcap|$)` - a positive lookahead that requires 0+ whitespaces, a word boundary and `Wordcap` string immediately to the right of the current location, or end of string.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/PxbGrW):

```
import re
rx = r"\bWordcap([^|=]*=.*?)(?=\s*\bWordcap|$)"
s = "Tue Apr 24 22:35:48 2018 53/e33 \nhello:55|Wordcap|abc|abc generate|6|Wordcapdata_proto_req=WINTER Wordcapdata_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5 WordcapTotal_reject=56 WordcapAddition_sum=TEA CUP ONE"
print(re.findall(rx, s))
# => ['data_proto_req=WINTER', 'data_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5', 'Total_reject=56', 'Addition_sum=TEA CUP ONE']
```

Comment: Hi @Wiktor
thanks for sharing the solution.

If I'm having "Wordcapdata_drive=\\\\10.10.10.2\\RECEIVE" in the input string.
Using the regex re.findall it parses the above string as "\\\\\\\\10.10.10.2\\\\RECEIVE"

I'm not sure why it adds the extra forward slash characters ! It tries to escape the forward slash, but I don't need these extra forward slashes. What might be the issue

Comment: @TanmaySawant There are no "extra" slashes, you just see them in the console. See [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: Hi @Wiktor

Suppose, after parsing through re.findall I get this output 
list1=["\\\\\\\\10.10.10.2\\\\RECEIVE"]

And I have one input list -> list2=['\\\\10.10.10.2\\RECEIVE"]

print list2[0] in list1
=> FALSE

So here in the list1 I've got the additional slashes, but when I have to compare list2 and list1, it throws False. But actually, those 2 strings should be the same.

Comment: @TanmaySawant Please share the whole relevant code, peferably via http://ideone.com. Note I have no idea how your `list2` is created. If manually, you should know how to insert ``\`` into a string literal. A single backslash is "coded" as either `"a\\b"` (regular string literal) or `r"a\b"` (raw string literal).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution,

```
myStr = """Tue Apr 24 22:35:48 2018 53/e33 hello:55| 
Wordcap|abc|abc generate|6|Wordcapdata_proto_req=WINTER 
Wordcapdata_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5 WordcapTotal_reject=56 
WordcapAddition_sum=TEA CUP ONE"""

print(re.findall(r'(?<=Wordcap)[^|]*?(?= Wordcap|$)', myStr))

# ['data_proto_req=WINTER', 'data_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5',
# 'Total_reject=56', 'Addition_sum=TEA CUP ONE']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
print(re.findall(r'Wordcap([^|].*?=.*?)(?= Wordcap|$)', string))
```

gives

```
['data_proto_req=WINTER', 'data_sample_resp=summer 2.4.5', 'Total_reject=56', 'Addition_sum=TEA CUP ONE']
```