# Python inconsistencies reading regex file

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, csv

I have a regex file that I am reading in and compiling.  The issue I am having is the regex will sometimes leading `\`.

```
Z\\d*\\.file_\\.?
```

instead of

```
Z\d*\.file_\.?
```

It sometimes matching but others not.

Comment: [mcve] please. it's unclear what your inputs are

Comment: Maybe another dupe of [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: We'll know when OP has edited

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely it does not match when you use raw string and double backslash.

```
s = "ABC 23"

re.findall('\d+',s)
['23']

re.findall(r'\d+',s)

['23']

re.findall('\\d+',s)
['23']

re.findall(r'\\d+',s)     

[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that is what you want but if you read [documentation of regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

It says :

> "Regular expressions use the backslash character ('\') to indicate
>   special forms or to allow special characters to be used without
>   invoking their special meaning"

And also :

> "The solution is to use Python’s raw string notation for regular
>   expression patterns; backslashes are not handled in any special way in
>   a string literal prefixed with 'r'"

Example:

```
regex= re.compile(r'string')
```