# Open function python

Tags: python

```
path=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'prueba.pdf')
print(path)
my_path=open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'prueba.pdf'), 'rb')
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLqmb.png)

Why do the two backslashes appear?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Because there is no such file in that directory , The error is self Explanatory

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: Is your question really about the backslashes, or about the exception you're getting from `open`?

Answer (score 1):

“Double backslashes” appear because they are getting [escaped](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/lexical_analysis.html#index-22). Windows paths use backslash (`\`) as separator, but these are the escape character. What you are seeing in the traceback is the `__repr__` of the `BASE_DIR` string, which shows escaped characters (*e.g.* `\\`) instead of the real characters (*e.g.* `\`). 
Here is an example in the Python interactive interpreter:

```python
>>> "\\"
"\\"
>>> print("\\".__repr__())
"\\"
>>> print(repr("\\"))
"\\"

# this time we are not calling repr
>>> print("\\")
"\"
```