# while giving a filepath as an argument in a function, why do we sometimes use a single "\" and sometimes a double "\\"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, filepath, backslash

For example, what is the difference between

```
import pandas as pd
dtf = pd.read_csv("c:\\pywork\\Employee.csv")
print(dtf)
```

and

```
import pandas as pd
dtf = pd.read_csv("c:\pywork\Employee.csv")
print(dtf)
```

Basically in both the cases, the only difference is the backslash, and from experience i have seen both function the same, but also seen the single backslash format give error or sometimes the double backslash format give errors. So what is the difference?

Comment: See [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: You can also check out Python 3 Quick Tip: "The easy way to deal with file paths on Windows, Mac and Linux " at https://medium.com/@ageitgey/python-3-quick-tip-the-easy-way-to-deal-with-file-paths-on-windows-mac-and-linux-11a072b58d5f