# How do you remove backslashes and the word attached to the backslash in Python?

Tags: python, string

I understand to remove a single backslash we might do something like
from [Removing backslashes from a string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160752/removing-backslashes-from-a-string-in-python)

I've attempted to:

I'd like to know how to remove in the list below all the words like '\ue606',

```
A = 
['Historical Notes 1996',
'\ue606',
'The Future of farms 2012',
'\ch889',
'\8uuuu',]
```

to transform it into

```
['Historical Notes 1996',
'The Future of farms 2012',]
```

I tried:

```
A = ['Historical Notes 1996',
'\ue606',
'The Future of farms 2012',
'\ch889',
'\8uuuu',]

for y in A:
      y.replace("\\", "")
A
```

It returns:

```
['Historical Notes 1996',
 '\ue606',
 'The Future of farms 2012',
 '\\ch889',
 '\\8uuuu']
```

I'm not sure how to address the string following the '\' or why it added a new '\' rather than remove it.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you getting stuck? Stack Overflow generally expects you to show a good-faith attempt at meeting your requirements on your own before posting here, in accordance with [ask].

Comment: Thanks @esqew for your feedback. I added my attempt at this. I'm quite new to python so I know my attempt is incorrect, but hopefully it offers some insight into where I am

Comment: The question isn't clear at all. The issue is that `'\ue606'` means a string with **one** character in it (which Python represents with a Unicode escape, but will print as ), but `"\ch889"` means a string with **six** characters in it - a backslash, lowercase c, etc. It is **necessary** to understand *what the data actually is*, and then show a [mre] that clarifies the problem properly.

Comment: Anyway, there seem to be two separate questions here: 1) why nothing was removed (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9189172/why-doesnt-calling-a-string-method-do-anything-unless-its-output-is-assigned); 2) why the backslashes are doubled up (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python is somewhat hard to convince to just ignore unicode characters. Here is a somewhat hacky attempt:

```
l = ['Historical Notes 1996',
'\ue606',
'The Future of farms 2012',
'\ch889',
'\8uuuu',]


def not_unicode_or_backslash(x):
    try:
        x = x.encode('unicode-escape').decode()
    finally:
        return not x.startswith("\\")
        

[x for x in l if not_unicode_or_backslash(x)]

# Output: ['Historical Notes 1996', 'The Future of farms 2012']
```

The problem is that you can't check directly whether or not the string starts with a backslash since `\ue606` is not considered as the 6-character string, but as a single unicode character. Because of this, it does not start with a backslash and for

```
[x for x in l if not x.startswith("\\")]
```

you get

```
['Historical Notes 1996', '\ue606', 'The Future of farms 2012']
```

Comment: OK -- that's helpful. It seems like python is reading something like \ue606 as a unicode character

Comment: @KatieMelosto Python 3 strings are *always* Unicode by definition.

Comment: @BoarGules - ok - thanks I did not  know that!

Comment: "Unicode characters" does not make very much sense and certainly isn't a meaningful distinction in the way that this answer implies.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I see what you mean. Do you have a suggestion on how to rephrase?

Comment: I don't think the question was well posed in the first place, so I don't know that I can give useful advice.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this.
Use isprintable() for unicode string and '\\' for strings start with backlash.

```
List = ['Historical Notes 1996','\ue606','The Future of farms 2012','\ch889','\8uuuu',]
print([x for x in List if x[0] != '\\' and x.isprintable()])
```

Comment: Thanks so much, @Osamu Zenji.  I also found this helpful website: https://java2blog.com/remove-unicode-characters-python/#:~:text=There%20are%20many%20ways%20to%20to%20remove%20unicode,%28%29%20method%20to%20decode%20%28%29%20it%20back.%201 about removing unicode