# Unwanted backslash ("\") appears in a string

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following function that constructs and returns a string (used to create a formula for Excel).

```
def create_hyperlink_formula(target_sheet,link_text):
    a = """=HYPERLINK("#'{target_sheet}'!$A$1),"{link_text}")""".format(target_sheet=target_sheet,
                                                                        link_text = link_text)
    return a
```

So by running:

```
create_hyperlink_formula(target_sheet = "Cover", link_text = "Return to cover page")
```

My desired result is as follows:

> =HYPERLINK("#'Cover'!$A$1),"Return to cover page")

But instead I get this:

> =HYPERLINK("#\'Cover\'!$A$1),"Return to cover page")

I cannot seem to get rid of the unwanted backslashes ("\") in this string.

I am completely lost as to why that happens and how to fix that. Even a workaround would help me a lot at this point, as string.replace() method doesn't help here either.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you seeing the backslashes? When I run the code in Python they aren't appearing. By the way, the desired result you indicate is not a valid Excel formula.

Comment: Related, but not an exact duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you are running this in the Python REPL / in the command line. The backslashes aren't actually there, it's just because running an expression will print its *representation* (`repr(x)`) not its *string form* (`str(x)`).

Try doing this in the command line, or saving it to a file or running it:

```python
def create_hyperlink_formula(target_sheet,link_text):
    a = """=HYPERLINK("#'{target_sheet}'!$A$1),"{link_text}")""".format(target_sheet=target_sheet,
                                                                        link_text = link_text)
    return a

print(create_hyperlink_formula(target_sheet = "Cover", link_text = "Return to cover page"))
```

Or, you can instead [try it online](https://tio.run/##rZBPC4JAEMXvfoptEnRBgugWeIgIiiLCWydZbPxDtivbGIn42Tc1sLx16F0f7/3mTVFRquTCmAvGLNIoCMO0KlDnmbyGsdK3MhcuCZ0ghfcUkbzeIXwSX1qslWA@AwB/ez5tgsPuuHdh6tTfkcaZ2Ct7zj2oh3ADvA3NOoKgEcAf0XrEPzSQ23M/E/p6jVRqyYRlFTqT5P70h271Wj1QgzfqhuDdRopFnc0KkSBwbswL) and observe that the result is as you want it.

Basically, the string `'` needs to be represented as `'\''` because `'''` isn't a valid Python expression, but as a string, it's just a single quotation mark. If the string actually had backslashes, it'd be `'\\\''` (or just `"\\'"`).