# How to use \ in a string without it's escape effect

Tags: python, string, escaping, special-characters

I'm trying to implement the next line:

```
with open('.\numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
```

The `\n` in the path is being recognized as the `new line` special character.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: Put another backslash before ```n```. Like this: ```with open('.\\numbers.txt', 'r') as f:```

Comment: Also, it is better to import ```os``` and use its utilities to do things related to paths and directories so that your program is compatible with different OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the raw string by prefixing the string with `r`

```py
print(r'.\numbers.txt')
```

Or escape the backslashes with `\\`

```py
print('.\\numbers.txt')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the escape character. So

```
with open('.\\numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
```

This should work for your needs.

Thanks
Scott.