# String Concatenation Clarification in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does the string concatenation operation **'A'+'\''+'B'+'\\'+'C'** produce the string **'A'B\\C'** instead of a single backslash. How to fix this?

And I don't want to make use of the print function to generate this pattern. I want this to be printed in the >>> prompt.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Post [mre]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why does the string concatenation operation 'A'+'''+'B'+'\'+'C' produce the string 'A'B\C' instead of a single backslash. How to fix this?

There's nothing to fix.

> And I don't want to make use of the print function to generate this pattern. I want this to be printed in the >>> prompt.

That's nonsensical and not possible.

The python console shows the *representation* (`repr`) of the object. The `repr` of a string always escapes backslashes (and includes delimiter quotes) such that it can be pasted as-is as a string literal.

That is also why it changes the delimiter quotes depending on what quote style is embedded in the string (if any):

```py
>>> '"'
'"'
>>> '\''
"'"
```