# Why does python add additional backslashes to the path?

Tags: python

I have a text file with a path that goes like this:

```
r"\\user\data\t83\rf\Desktop\QA"
```

When I try to read this file a print a line it returns the following string, I'm unable to open the file from this location:

```
'r"\\\\user\\data\\t83\\rf\\Desktop\\QA"\n'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: Thanks. Answers, but doesn't help resolve my problem at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you've got Python code in your text file, so either sanitize your file, so it only includes the actual path (not a Python string representation) or you can try to fiddle with string replace until you're satisfied, or just evaluate the Python string.

Note that using `eval()` opens Padora's box (it as unsafe as it gets), it's safer to use `ast.literal_eval()` instead.

```
import ast
file_content = 'r"\\\\user\\data\\t83\\rf\\Desktop\\QA"\n'
print(eval(file_content)) # do not use this, it's only shown for the sake of completeness
print(ast.literal_eval(file_content))
```

Output:

```
\\user\data\t83\rf\Desktop\QA        
\\user\data\t83\rf\Desktop\QA
```

Personally, I'd prefer to sanitize the file, so it only contains `\\user\data\t83\rf\Desktop\QA`

Comment: Thanks Mike. I got your point. Managed to read the paths and list files within the directories.

Answer (score 0):

`\` will wait for another character to form one like `\n` (new line) or `\t` (tab) therefore a single backslash will merge with the next character. To solve this if the next character is `\\` it will represent the single backslash.

Comment: \ works as an escape character to escape next character.

Comment: Ok, so I used pth.replace(r'\\', ''), which I print and looks more like a python path now: r"\\user\data\t83\rf\Desktop\QA Then I pass it to open() function. and what I see? I see OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'r"user\\data\\t83\\rf\\Desktop\\QA' I really don't understand what is happening here.