# perform a split on a string with special characters

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem when trying to convert a string containing special characters to a list using a split and save result to josn. For example:

```
t="machine,machine\c&"

p=t.split(",")

host = {}
host['name'] = p[0]
host['filespace'] = p[1]

with open('json_host.json', 'w') as file:
    json.dump(host, file, indent=4)
```

return:

```
{
    "name": "machine",
    "filespace": "machine\\c&"
}
```

I need the return conver only one \

```
{
    "name": "machine",
    "filespace": "machine\c&"
}
```

I have tried to use a replace but it does not work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Answer (score 0):

The backslash is only once there

When you print as

```
print(p)
```

you get list to string representation where the list looks like you have typed it in your code. The backslash should be escaped. Python knows that there is no combination like \c so allows not escaped variant.

If you print real values of the list, you get as it is:

```
print(' | '.join(p))

machine |  machine\c&
```

or char by char:

```
print(p[1][7], p[1][8], p[1][9])

e \ c
```