# How to set a single "\" in a filename (I've tried all the ways I could find}

Tags: python

I have a script that should rename the file default.xex to the value of FileName[:-1] which is the name of the directory the xex file is in. The code I have is:

`

```
# This renames default.xex to the correct FileName.xex
    for filename in DirectoryList:
        path = HomePath + UnpackedPath + FileName + FileName + FileName + FileName
        filename = FileName[:-1] + "\\default.xex"
        src = filename
        dst = FileName[:-1] + ".xex"
        os.rename(os.path.join(path, src), os.path.join(path, dst))
```

`

however this always throws an error showing \FileName.xex when \FileName.xex is expected.
The error is:

Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/corey/XBLA_Unpacked/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon\default.xex' -> '/home/corey/XBLA_Unpacked/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon/FarCry 3 Blood Dragon.xex'

## This renames default.xex to the correct FileName.xex

```
for filename in DirectoryList:
    path = HomePath + UnpackedPath + FileName + FileName + FileName + FileName
    filename = FileName[:-1] + "\\default.xex"
    src = filename
    dst = FileName[:-1] + ".xex"
    os.rename(os.path.join(path, src), os.path.join(path, dst))
```

Edit: I just realized this only shows 1 , however on my screen in VS Code and in this text editor it shows 2

the original xex file is FarCry 3 Blood Dragon\default.xex.

I have tried every solution I could find while googling and looking at other people's solutions on here and nothing seems to work. I tried setting it as a specific string variable and running it that way and it still resulted in \.

Comment: You say `this always prints two`. Nowhere in your code are you printing anything.  Please make a code example that reproduces the problem you are having.

Comment: I have added more information per your comment. it doesnt print two, but throws and error message that shows two

Comment: Probably same root issue as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice).

Comment: I read through a lot of those posts. Using r"\defult.xex" seemed promising but alas it still looked for two \ as shown in the error message

Answer (score 1):

The error message is showing the [`repr`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/4177009) of the string, in order to be unambiguous if there are any "strange" characters in there. **There is only one backslash in the string**, but just as it has to be doubled when it occurs in a string literal, it will be doubled in the output, because a single backslash would be used for special characters.

For example, if I run the following program

```
import os
f='a\\b'
print(len(f))
os.rename(f, 'foo')
```

it prints `3`, showing that the string is just 3 characters, but then it gives the error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'a\\b' -> 'foo'
```