# Python adding a double backslash when escaping string

Tags: python, escaping

I work with devices such as routers and switches. I am trying to set up some banners on the devices based on user input.
Since we cant know how the user would give an input(escaped or otherwise), I am trying to add escape characters to ', " and \

```
Input:
"switch_mgmt": {
    "cli_banner": '\t\n"test"'
}    

def QUOTED_ESCAPED(name):
    return r'%s' % name.replace('\"', '\\"')

cli_banner = get_str(self.device_mgmt.get('cli_banner'), None)
    if cli_banner:
        ensure_dict(dict1, "system", "login").update({
                "message": QUOTED_ESCAPED(cli_banner)
        })
```

But python returns with \\" and so the final command generated which is pushed to the device has a \\ instead of a \ ".

The ensure_dict function basically just makes sure (dict1, "system", "login") is an existing dict or if not, it creates it and assigns a {} to it.

Any reason why Python is adding the extra escaped character? Is there a way I can just add \"?

I want to store '\"test\"' into message. But its storing '\\"test\\"' into message.
Hence command generated at the end is 'set system login message '\\"test\\"' '

I am looking to get 'set system login message '\"test\"' '

Edit:
[image]

I need to use the printed result in the variable. If I use the variable directly, it will keep the \

Update:

So it seems multiline strings store escaped quotes with single escape characters. But replace or re.sub still involves the python interpreter and it adds the extra \ to the replaced characters

Comment: `b` is a string that consists of: backslash, quotation mark, t, e, s, t, backslash, quotation mark. Is that what you want?

Comment: I want to use the escaped string as an element in the dictionary. dict = {'message': b}. this will eventually create a set command for a switch device. Something like 'set login message '\"test\"' '. But when storing to the dict, it stores \\"test\\" which generates 'set login message '\\"test\\"' '

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do backslashes appear twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24085680/why-do-backslashes-appear-twice)

Comment: Not really. I understand why python adds \ now.. But i still am not able to get the expected output. I just want a variable with single escape sequence. I want the function to return '\"test\"'

Comment: It does. You only think it doesn't. (I think.) How do you look at the output?

Comment: The problem is not the output.. I dont intend to print or write to file. If i was, I would see the proper escaped text.  I want to use the var as a dict element.  Since I am using the variable as is, and adding it to "" and using that as an element of a dictionary, it is preserving the \\ instead of \ .

Comment: final value generated is 
'set groups top system login message " \\"test\\" " '. 
Here i just want it as 
'set groups top system login message " \"test\" " '

Comment: What happens if you pretend that what you have is correct? Does the rest of the code which receives the supposedly wrong value work?

Comment: rest of the code just creates the set command based of the dictionary. Since dictionary has the value \\"\\" it uses it as is. This generates the set command as 'set groups top system login message " \\"test\\" " '
so when this command is applied to the device, device thinks \ is escaped and not "
so message becomes \"test\" instead of "test"

Comment: Why did you use `name.replace('\"', '\\"')`? What happens if you don't use it?

Comment: The user will have a text box to enter the message he wishes to push to the device. The device accepts message in "". If we dont escape ", the message might end abruptly or throw an error. 
Example:

set system login message "this is a "test message"". 
In above case, it will only accept "this is a "

Comment: "Since we cant know how the user would give an input" -- that's why it's important for the *user* to provide the correct input, instead of expecting a program to magically clean up their mistakes.

Comment: @chepner I understand that. but the issue still remains.. Python interpreter adds an extra \ when replacing " with \". I understand why. When we print the variable we will see correct output \". But when adding this as a dict element, it keeps the \\ which I want to remove

Comment: `b` only contains two backslashes. You are confusing the *representation* of `b` with its actual content. Say you set `x = '\\'`. `len(x)` shows that the string contains exactly one character, the backslash produced by the digraph ``\\`` in the string literal. If you use `print(x)`, you'll see exactly that one character written to the screen. If you use `x`, you'll see the 4 characters in the string returned by `repr(x)`, namely `'`, ``\``, ``\``, and `'`.