# How to replace special character in a file using Python?

Tags: python

I have data like this in file. I want replace the backslash from the entire data. I tried to use replace function after reading this text file but could not get the result. Could you please help.

```
[{"Name": "Segment1", "Value": 14.0, "Categories": "{\"MILL CREEK\": 0.0, \"FAIRPORT\": 1.0, \"PENNINGTON\": 0.0, \"GREENWICH\": 0.0
```

Comment: Hi Shankar, it is always helpful to post the code which you have tried.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to replace back slash character with empty string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618030/how-to-replace-back-slash-character-with-empty-string-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape backslash char

```
str.replace('\\', "")
```