# If character in string put escape character "\" in front of the found character

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am requesting an API which sometimes gives a string that contain "*" characters.
I have to post the output on discord, where ** makes the text bold.
I want to see if a string contains any * and if so put a markdown \ escape character in front of the *.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `string_name.replace("*", "\*")`?

Comment: [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to replace back slash character with empty string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618030/how-to-replace-back-slash-character-with-empty-string-in-python)

Comment: @RandomDavis can you make it an answer so I can accept it as the solution.
And thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Random Davis rightly pointed out in the comments, you can use `str.replace("*","\*")`and it will replace all the * occurrence.

Comment: it would be best to also add an example so OP can see clearly how the solution works

Comment: @JoeFerndz, I agree, that would normally be appreciated. But I understood it and it's working now :)