# Regular expression quoting in Python

Tags: python, regex

How should I declare a regular expression?

```
mergedData = re.sub(r'\$(.*?)\$', readFile, allData)
```

I'm kind of wondering why this worked. I thought that I need to use the `r''` to pass a regular expression.

```
mergedData = re.sub("\$(.*?)\$", readFile, allData)
```

What does `"\$"` result in in this case? Why? I would have thought `"$"`.

Comment: Why do you revert the edit? `r''` and `"\$"` are code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I thought that I need to user the r'' to pass a regular expression.

`r` before a string literal indicates raw string, which means the usual escape sequences such as `\n` or `\r` are no longer treated as new line character or carriage return, but simply `\` followed by `n` or `r`. To specify a `\`, you only need `\` in raw string literal, while you need to double it up `\\` in normal string literal. This is why it is usually the case that raw string is used in specifying regular expression<sup>1</sup>. It reduces the confusion when reading the code. You would have to do escaping twice if you use normal string literal: once for the normal string literal escape and the second time for the escaping in regex.

> What does `"\$"` result in this case? Why? I would have thought `"$"`

In Python normal string literal, if `\` is not followed by an escape sequence, the `\` is preserved. Therefore `"\$"` results in `\` followed by `$`.

This behavior is slightly different from the way C/C++ or JavaScript handle similar situation: the `\` is considered escape for the next character, and only the next character remains. So `"\$"` in those languages will be interpreted as `$`.

**Footnote**

<sup>1</sup>: There is a small defect with the design of raw string in Python, though: [Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: Thanks.  I guess I was confused by C.  ( I'm always confused by C. )

Answer (score 3):

The `r'...'` [escapes sequences](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) like `'\1'` (reference to first group in a regular expression, but the same as `'\x01`' if not escaped).

Generally speaking in `r'...'` the backslash won't behave as an escape character.

Try

```
 re.split('(.).\1', '1x2x3')  # ['1x2x3']
```

vs.

```
 re.split(r'(.).\1', '1x2x3') # ['1', 'x', '3']
```

As `'\$'` is not an escape sequence in python, it is literally the same as `'\\$'`.

Answer (score 1):

Just ask the snake:

```
>>> r'\$(.*?)\$'=='\$(.*?)\$'
True
>>> r'\vert'=='\vert'
False
>>> r'\123'=='\123'
False
>>> r'\#23'=='\#23'
True
```

Basically if `\x` [would create an esacped character in C](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals), using r in a string prefix is the same as `\\x`:

```
>>> r'\123'=='\\123'
True
>>> r'\tab'=='\\tab'
True
```