# How to assign \ character to a variable in Python?

Tags: python

[image][image][image]I am trying to assign 
user = 'corp\adam'

Using python I am unable to create a user variable as desire. 
Desired Output:

user

'corp\adam'

I don't want to print the variable. I need to store it.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2):

In Python (and commonly in other programming languages too) the backslash character is used to denote special characters that could not be typed directly into a string. This is known as an escape sequence. To specify a literal backslash, use it twice:

`user = 'corp\\adam'`

Comment: This isn't working.  Output based on your suggestion is 'corp\\adam' . Can you check on your end ?

Comment: @GauravP that *is what you are asking for*.

Comment: If you're inspecting the value of `user` directly (e.g. by using the python interpreter) it will output the same way it is input. However the actual string representation has only one backslash: `len('\\') # returns 1`

Comment: Can you check by doing it ? I uploaded the screenshot for your ease.

Comment: @GauravP it has been explained to you **repeatedly** that you are seeing the `repr` of the string, not the string itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try a double backslash, i.e. corp\\adam. The first backslash denotes that the second one has to be evaluated like a normal character, not as another escape character.

Comment: This may also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327202/python-replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslash

Answer (score 0):

You can use `r'corp\adam'` that way you tell Python it's a "raw" string and the backslash will not be used to escape other characters.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html):

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat backslashes as literal characters.

Comment: r'corp\adam'    results in output = 'corp\\adam'  . I tried just know

Comment: @GauravP: That's because you output the `repr` of the string (you probably just type the variable's name in the interactive interpreter). If you did `print(output)` the extra backslash wouldn't be there.

Comment: @GauravP That is the `repr` of the string, not the string itself. Using either a raw string or the double-backslash is the correct answer

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillage  - i need to use the variable later on as a password field. I don't want to print it.

Comment: @GauravP yes, so? What is it that you are not understanding? If you want, inspect the string character by character and you'll see it is *exactly what you want*. You are confused about the `repr`

Comment: config  = dict(server = 'servername' , username = 'crop\adam') .      Now i need to use this config variable in conn = pyodbc.connect(
    r'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};' +
    conn_str.format(**config)
    )

Comment: however when you try to see what config is  username = 'corp\\adam' and not 'corp\adam'

Comment: @GauravP You need `config = dict(server = 'servername' , username = r'crop\adam')`. Or `config = dict(server = 'servername' , username = 'crop\\adam')`. Either one of those gives you what you need

Comment: Can you paste the screenshot by trying it ? I have tried what you mentioned but it doesn't work.

Comment: I uploaded the screenshot . Please check

Comment: This is getting boring. Please write the string to a file or to a DB or something, but stop saying that it does not work by looking at the ``repr`` of the string instead of the actual character values.

Comment: @GauravP Yes I see it. And it is *correct*. I and others have already explained to you why you are seeing the extra backslash in the terminal output.

Comment: I am sorry for this and i agree with you . Now i uploaded a screenshot. How do i ensure that my pyodbc read the username as corp\adam and not as corp\\adam

Comment: @GauravP are you trolling? It is doing that already in your screenshot.

Comment: dude - it says Login failed for 'corp\\adam' . It is sending a wrong string to the odbc connection. It should be sending 'corp\adam' . Are you not getting me ? Database is receiving 'corp\\adam' as a username string while it should be receiving 'corp\adam'

Comment: @GauravP dude, I'm almost *certain* that that's because the error message prints the *representation* of the string. The quotes are a dead give-away. Try giving it `username="test\bname"`. What does the error message print now?

Comment: @GauravP here are the three possibilities, I think. 1) your working environment has been cluttered by all the debugging you are doing. Somewhere, somehow, `config` is being shadowed with the wrong parameters. 2) whatever sql server library you are using is post-processing the string somehow, messing it up 3) the login is failing for some other reason. However, regardless, **the string you have assigned to that `config` dictionary is the string you are asking for**.

Comment: @GauravP If you do narrow the issue down, ask another question or edit this one but you have give *way more* detail about the issue. As it stands, the question you are asking here is *answered*.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash character acts as an escape when the next character is an ASCII or Python special escape character. Either escape the backslash with another backslash:

```
 'corp\\adam'
```

or use a raw string (where backslash only escapes the quote character it doesn't even escape itself):

```
 r'corp\adam'
```