# How to add escape char before each hex char? Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm' trying to convert string to JSON file using the `json.dump` method.
Before the conversion, I need to add escape character before each char that represented as hex for example `'\x00'` or `'\x96'`.

In the end I need to convert string like:

```
'\x94\xa0aaa'
```

To:

```
'\\x94\\xa0aaa'
```

How can I do it? I tried to use the `replace` method, but it didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python replace single backslash with double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327202/python-replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslash)

Comment: *I need to convert...* No, you don't, json knows about that: `json.dumps('\x94\xa0aaa')` directly gives: `'"\\u0094\\u00a0aaa"'`

Answer (score 1):

The backslash has a special meaning in Python.
If you define a literal string like '\x94\xa0aaa' there is no real backslash in it.
If you define it raw like r'\x94\xa0aaa' there are real backslashes.

In your replace() call you have to double the backslashes because raw strings can not end with a backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re
old = r'\x94\xa0aaa'
new = re.sub(r"\\", r"\\\\", old)
print(new)

Result:  \\x94\\xa0aaa
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course it didn't. The first line is the representation of one string, the second one is the representation of another one.

This is what you can do:

```
a = '\x94\xa0aaa' # displays as '\x94\xa0aaa', but indeed contains 94 and a0 in hex, followed by three "a", so 94a0616161
b = a.repr() # displays as '\\x94\\xa0aaa', but indeed contains '\x94\xa0aaa', i. e. 5c7839345c786130616161.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bs = chr(92)
print(r"\x94\xa0aaa".replace(bs,bs*2))
```

`92` stands for `\` ascii number.