# Using two \\ instead of \ to get rid of (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'

Tags: python

**UPDATED CODE:**

```
file_name2 =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott\initialTrades.csv'
df=pd.read_excel(file_name2)

print (df)
```

This returns error XLRDError.

```
file_name2 =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott\initialTrades.xlsx'
df=pd.read_excel(file_name2)

print (df)
```

This returns error: FileNotFoundError.

---

file_name ='C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott'
    file_double="C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott"

I put two \ instead of \ as [python replace single backslash with double backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17327202/python-replace-single-backslash-with-double-backslash) this article states to ger rid of the (unicode error) 'unicodeescape'

What small step am I missing?

Here is the rest of my code:

```
sheet =initialTrades #I also tried 'initialTrades'

df = pd.read_excel(io=file_double, sheet_name=sheet)
print(df.head(5))  # print first 5 rows of the dataframe
```

Comment: did you read the *answer* on that link too? try with a simple `r` flag. `file_name =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott'`

Comment: I tried a various number of answers yes. Most of them vary in different ways which makes me unclear of which one is actually the 'right' answe

Comment: For instance, `directory = str(r"C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott").replace('\\','\\\\') `still gets the same error.

Comment: don't do all that. where did `directory` come from? Just, clear everything, start over, use a `r` before the fullpath. that's it. `file_name =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott'` then you should get more useful errors or atleast focus on the more concerning things, such as the fact that the path you've given here is clearly not an excel file, it seems like just until the folder.

Comment: `file_name2 =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott'
sheet =initialTrades

df = pd.read_excel(io=file_name2, sheet_name=sheet)
print(df.head(5))  # print first 5 rows of the dataframe`   This code still gets the same error. So I am using an Excel file, but it is CSV (comma delim). That could be the issue...

Comment: and? what happens? (also, what is `initialTrades`?)

Comment: initialTrades is the Excel (CSV delim) file name. The code above gets the same error still.

Comment: ack. just write `file_name2 =r'C:\Users\Trading\Desktop\scott\initialTrades.xlsx'` (im assuming .xlsx format, you never mentioned it. is it .csv instead??) . and then just `pd.read_excel(file_name2)`.

Comment: Ok I agree with your code but got a FileNotFoundError. Yes it is an excel CSV file.   I also tried .csv. and got a XLRDError

Comment: can you edit the code you tried and the error into the question please?

Comment: good idea. I just updated the code on very top.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195528/discussion-between-paritosh-singh-and-john-smith).