# backslash in $ python -c "script"

Tags: python, shell, terminal, latex, backslash

Today I wrote a Python script to process data and print them in customized format. It worked as expected under interactive Python. Then I moved on to try in Terminal to redirect the output to a text file, and encountered something unexpected.

The particular example I tried was to arrange a list of data in columns, and print them in LaTeX tabular format. It works more or less like:

```
foo(mylist, sep_col='\t', sep_row=r'\\ \hline')
```

When I tried to run the script in Terminal, I did this:

```
$ python -c "from foo import foo; foo(mylist, col_sep=' & ', row_sep=r' \\ \hline')" > results.txt
```

But it turned out that the `\\ \hline` part was shown as `\ \hline`, which is not the same as under interactive Python.

As I looked into the problem (or maybe the principles behind) more, I found that the behavior of the Python script processed by `$ python -c` is not the same under interactive Python.

Under interactive Python: `>>> print r'\\'` gives `\\`

However, in Terminal, `$ python -c "print r'\\'"` raises a `SyntaxError`:

```
  File "<string>", line 1
    print r'\'
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Terminal seems to give `\\` when the number of backslash is 3 or 4. Number 5 or 6 raises an error. 7 backslashes give `\\\\`, which means there is no way to give `\\\` under this environment.

I've searched for this issue for quite a while, but it seems very few talks about `$ python -c`. Sorry in advance if I made a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terminal, saying:

```
$ python -c "print r'\\'"
  File "<string>", line 1
    print r'\'
             ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

results in an error because the shell comes into play.  It *translates* `\\` into `\` (see the error message carefully).

Instead, say

```
$ python -c 'print r"\\"'
\\
```

when running from the shell, i.e. supply the command in single quotes and arguments to `print` in double quotes.

The equivalent of the command that you were executing in interactive mode would be:

```
$ python -c "print r'\\\\'"
\\
```

EDIT: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/647787/2235132) answer explains why a raw string cannot have an odd number of backslashes.

Moreover, this is also explained in the official [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash).

Comment: Thanks for you answer. But wait, why it still doesn't work for `$ python -c 'print r"\\\"'`?

Comment: @kctong529 The [FAQ](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-can-t-raw-strings-r-strings-end-with-a-backslash) also explains it.

Comment: By the way, do you think passing raw strings involving backslashes to a Python script as some of the `argv` arguments is a good habit?

Comment: I'd avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell interprets the backslashes inside the double quotes as well.  You can use single quotes to avoid this; then you will have to change your single quotes in the python script to double quotes instead:

```
python -c 'from foo import foo; foo(mylist, col_sep=" & ", row_sep=r" \\ \hline")'
```

You could have used `echo` debugging in this case:  Simply write `echo` before your shell command to see what is about to get executed:

```
echo python -c "print r'\\'"
```

shows:

```
python -c print r'\'
```

Comment: Do you mean single quote means more to shell interpretation than double quote?
The `echo` debugging helps. But `echo python -c 'print r"\\\"'`, which shows `python -c print r"\\\"`, still raises a `SyntaxError`

Comment: Yes, single quotes and double quotes have different meaning in shell (but that's not the topic here).  The `python -c print r"\\\"` in your example is a syntax error because it contains an unterminated string; it starts like this: backslash (denoted by two of them), double quote (denoted by a blackslash and a double quote) and then lacks a closing double quote.  Try it like this: `print "\\\""`  This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal does not recognise raw or regex strings, i.e. `r'something'` as anything special and all backslashes need to be escaped by backslashes in the terminal, so:

```
python -c "from foo import foo; foo(mylist, col_sep=' & ', row_sep=r' \\ \hline')" > results.tx
```

needs to be:

```
python -c "from foo import foo; foo(mylist, col_sep=' & ', row_sep=r' \\\\ \\hline');" > results.tx
```

and

```
foo(mylist, sep_col='\t', sep_row=r'\\ \hline')
```

would map to:

```
python -c "from foo import foo; foo(mylist, sep_col='\\t', sep_row=r'\\\\ \\hline');"
```

Comment: This makes sense, just that I didn't realize the fact (that Terminal does not recognise raw or regex strings). Do you think it is unwise to use raw strings as a habit?

Comment: Not within python - without them when calling from terminal row_sep would be ' \\\\\\\\ \\\\hline' i.e. doubled for python and doubled again for terminal.