# Python insert "\" in string

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to insert a backslash in a string but when I do this:

```
s1='cn=Name Surname (123)'
s1[:17] + '\' + s1[17:]
```

I get

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

Also, tried this but it inserts 2 backslashes

```
s1[:17] + '\\' + s1[17:]
```

The final string should look like this

```
s1='cn=Name Surname \(123\)'
```

Comment: Have you tried `r'\'`?

Comment: @thegrinner, `r'\'` is not a valid string. Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: @thegrinner: that is the *one* thing you cannot do in a raw string. You cannot end it in one slash.

Comment: @thegrinner, `r'\'` is not working. String(including raw string) cannot ends with odd number of `\ `.

Comment: @soon Ah, interesting. Never ran into that before. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @sergei "but it inserts 2 backslashes" no, it doesn't. It only looks so for representation purposes.

Comment: @sergei, you were right the second time. Try len('\\').

Comment: Yeah, beginners mistakes I guess? I need to remember to print the output first, ask later.

Comment: @thegrinner  Have you tried ``r'\'``?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here:

```
>>> s1 = 'cn=Name Surname (123)'
>>> x = s1[:16]+'\\'+s1[16:-1]+'\\'+s1[-1:]
>>> x
'cn=Name Surname \\(123\\)'
>>> print x
cn=Name Surname \(123\)
>>>
```

You have to print the string.  Otherwise, you will see `\\` (which is used in the interpreter to show a literal backslash).

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s1='cn=Name Surname (123)'
>>> s1[:17] + '\\' + s1[17:]
'cn=Name Surname (\\123)'
```

It seems like two backslash, but it's actually containing only one backslash.

```
>>> print(s1[:17] + '\\' + s1[17:])
cn=Name Surname (\123)
>>> print s1[:17] + '\\' + s1[17:-1] + '\\' + s1[-1:]
cn=Name Surname (\123\)
```

Comment: You got the print part right but the final result isn't like he wanted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just entering it in the python command line interpreter and pressing enter, it will show up as two backslashes because the interpreter shows the escape character.  However, if you saved it to a file, or if you used it in a "print" command it will suppress the escape character and print the actual value, which in this case is just one backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Can something like this suffice?

```
print(s1.replace('(', '\\(').replace(')', '\\)'))
```

Comment: That doesn't answers the question.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Right. I fixed it.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Yes, it inserts 2 backslashes to get the second one right. Have you run the code?

Comment: I know your code works but question was why I am getting `\\ ` in the output?(repr vs str)Add explanation related to that in your answer.

Comment: He was actually getting a `SyntaxError`, plus there was an issue with the index used to insert the char. Can't see any question about "why".

Answer (score 0):

```
for folder in Chart_Folders:
    files = os.listdir(path + '\\' + folder)
    print(files)
```

indeed this works

Comment: This doesn't address the question.