# Parse directory path to a variable in python

Tags: python

I want to parse to var and set what i parse to a variable 
I want to parse  `C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8 and make it into`level7\level8`
currently i am able to get level7 only

```
var = "C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8"

split_path = os.path.split(os.path.split(var)[0])

print split_path
```

output below

```
('C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6', 'level7')
```

Comment: " I want to parse level7\\level8 and make it into level7\level8" - makes no sense. elaborate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> var = "C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8"
>>> var.split('\\', 7)
['C:', 'level1', 'level2', 'level3', 'level4', 'level5', 'level6', 'level7\\level8']
>>> var.split('\\', 7)[-1]
'level7\\level8'
```

I don't get the same output as you with your code. It could be because I'm on OSX and that isn't recognized as a file path. Regardless, this solution is a bit simpler and gives you the bit you want.

The second parameter tells split the max number of times to split counting from left, so:

```
>>> var.split('\\', 1)
['C:', 'level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8']
>>> var.split('\\', 2)
['C:', 'level1', 'level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8']
# and so on...
```

You don't need to do anything to remove the extra `'\'`, it's there to escape the one you want. You can see this by using `print()`:

```
>>> print(var.split('\\', 7)[-1])
level7\level8
```

Comment: There's a reason he uses `os.path.split`. It makes the code portable.

Comment: `os.path.split` doesn't do anything to that string, which I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: If you still don't get it, look up the documentation.

Comment: Looking at the documentation makes it clear `os.path.split` doesn't do what the OP wants. `"The tail part will never contain a slash"` seems to be at direct odds with what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you only get 'level7' is because 'level8' is in

```
os.path.split(var)[1]
```

This should demonstrate it clearly:

```
var = "C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8"
split_path = os.path.split(var)
level8 = split_path[1]
split_path = os.path.split(split_path[0])
level7 = split_path[1]
my_split_path = (split_path[0], os.path.join(level7, level8)
```

Here's the whole thing in one line:

```
my_split_path = (os.path.split(os.path.split(var)[0])[0], os.path.split(os.path.join(os.path.split(var)[0][1], os.path.split(var)[1])))
```

I'd recommend using multiple lines for clarity though.

As far as the double backslashes, Python string literals treat the first backslash as an escape character. So having two of them is effectively having one of them for all uses. In the interpreter `var` will output the string as you have it above, but `print(var)` will print single backslashes. This question has been answered in detail here: [Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: there was a guy who ansered with a function where you can pass path and step where did he go?

Comment: I'm not sure, I didn't notice that post. You can easily do that with the code above in a loop though.