# Formatting json data fetched from URL by removing escape character

Tags: python, json

I have fetched json data  from url and write it to in a file name urljson.json
i want to format the json data removing '\' and result [] key for requirment purpose
In my json file the data are arranged like this

```
{\"result\":[{\"BldgID\":\"1006AVE \",\"BldgName\":\"100-6th Avenue SW (Oddfellows)          \",\"BldgCity\":\"Calgary             \",\"BldgState\":\"AB \",\"BldgZip\":\"T2G 2C4  \",\"BldgAddress1\":\"100-6th Avenue Southwest                \",\"BldgAddress2\":\"ZZZ None\",\"BldgPhone\":\"4035439600     \",\"BldgLandlord\":\"1006AV\",\"BldgLandlordName\":\"100-6 TH Avenue SW Inc.                                     \",\"BldgManager\":\"AVANDE\",\"BldgManagerName\":\"Alyssa Van de Vorst           \",\"BldgManagerType\":\"Internal\",\"BldgGLA\":\"34242\",\"BldgEntityID\":\"1006AVE \",\"BldgInactive\":\"N\",\"BldgPropType\":\"ZZZ None\",\"BldgPropTypeDesc\":\"ZZZ None\",\"BldgPropSubType\":\"ZZZ None\",\"BldgPropSubTypeDesc\":\"ZZZ None\",\"BldgRetailFlag\":\"N\",\"BldgEntityType\":\"REIT                     \",\"BldgCityName\":\"Calgary             \",\"BldgDistrictName\":\"Downtown            \",\"BldgRegionName\":\"Western Canada                                    \",\"BldgAccountantID\":\"KKAUN     \",\"BldgAccountantName\":\"Kendra Kaun                   \",\"BldgAccountantMgrID\":\"LVALIANT  \",\"BldgAccountantMgrName\":\"Lorretta Valiant                        \",\"BldgFASBStartDate\":\"2012-10-24\",\"BldgFASBStartDateStr\":\"2012-10-24\"}]}
```

I want it like this format

```
[  
   {  
      "BldgID":"1006AVE",
      "BldgName":"100-6th Avenue SW (Oddfellows)          ",
      "BldgCity":"Calgary             ",
      "BldgState":"AB ",
      "BldgZip":"T2G 2C4  ",
      "BldgAddress1":"100-6th Avenue Southwest                ",
      "BldgAddress2":"ZZZ None",
      "BldgPhone":"4035439600     ",
      "BldgLandlord":"1006AV",
      "BldgLandlordName":"100-6 TH Avenue SW Inc.                                    ",
      "BldgManager":"AVANDE",
      "BldgManagerName":"Alyssa Van de Vorst           ",
      "BldgManagerType":"Internal",
      "BldgGLA":"34242",
      "BldgEntityID":"1006AVE ",
      "BldgInactive":"N",
      "BldgPropType":"ZZZ None",
      "BldgPropTypeDesc":"ZZZ None",
      "BldgPropSubType":"ZZZ None",
      "BldgPropSubTypeDesc":"ZZZ None",
      "BldgRetailFlag":"N",
      "BldgEntityType":"REIT                     ",
      "BldgCityName":"Calgary             ",
      "BldgDistrictName":"Downtown            ",
      "BldgRegionName":"Western Canada                                    ",
      "BldgAccountantID":"KKAUN     ",
      "BldgAccountantName":"Kendra Kaun                   ",
      "BldgAccountantMgrID":"LVALIANT  ",
      "BldgAccountantMgrName\":"      Lorretta Valiant                        ",
      "BldgFASBStartDate":"2012-10-24",
      "BldgFASBStartDateStr":"2012-10-24"
   }   `
]
```

i have tried replace("\","") but nothing changed 
Here is my  code

```
import json


import urllib2
urllink=urllib2.urlopen("url").read()

print urllink -commented out



with open('urljson.json','w')as outfile:
    json.dump(urllink,outfile)


jsonfile='urljson.json'
jsondata=open(jsonfile)

data=json.load(jsondata)
data.replace('\'," ") --commented out
print (data)
```

but it is saying fileobject has no replace attribute, I didnt find any idea how to remove 'result' and most outer "{}"
kindly guide me
i think the file object is not parsed in string somehow .i am beginner in python
thank you

Comment: A suggestion, You may use `json.loads()` and `json.dumps()` instead of `json.load()` and `json.dump()` they directly take file path as param so you dont read to `open` file and `read` data from it

Comment: @ZdaR - no, they take a json string, not the path to a string.

Comment: I'm confused about that first string you showed us. Its not json but it looks like the python representation of a json string. So, where did it come from?

Comment: You save to a file... did you want to keep a copy or was that just an intermediate step for the decode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSON is a serialized encoding for data. `urllink=urllib2.urlopen("url").read()` read that serialized string. With `json.dump(urllink,outfile)` you serialized that single serialized JSON string again. You double-encoded it and that's why you see those extra "\" escape characters. json needs to escape those characters so as not to confuse them with the quotes it uses to demark strings.

If you wanted the file to hold the original json, you wouldn't need to encode it again, just do

```
with open('urljson.json','w')as outfile:
    outfile.write(urllink)
```

But it looks like you want to grab the "result" list and only save that. So, decode the JSON into python, grab the bits you want, and encode it again.

```
import json
import codecs
import urllib2

# read a json string from url
urllink=urllib2.urlopen("url").read()

# decode and grab result list
result = json.loads(urllink)['result']

# write the json to a file
with open('urljson.json','w')as outfile:
    json.dump(result, outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidy up the JSON object before writing it to file. It has lot of whitespace noise. Try like this:

```
urllink = {a.strip():b.strip() for a,b in json.loads(urllink).values()[0][0].items()}
jsonobj = json.loads(json.dumps(urllink))

with open('urljson.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(jsonobj, outfile)
```

For all objects:

```
jsonlist = []

for dirtyobj in json.loads(urllink)['result']:
     jsonlist.append(json.loads(json.dumps({a.strip():b.strip() for a,b in dirtyobj.items()})))

with open('urljson.json','w') as outfile:
    json.dump(json.loads(json.dumps(jsonlist)), outfile)
```

---

Don't wanna tidy up? Then simply do this:

```
jsonobj = json.loads(urllink)
```

---

And you can't do `'\'`, it's syntax error. The second `'` is escaped and is not considered as closing quote.

```
data.replace('\'," ")
```

[Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash)

Comment: Thank you for that tidy code but  it is showing only first index json elements  how could i do it for full json set. the length of the array is 23510
and for bigger number it is showing index out of bound  and if i remove [][]items and keeping value() then it is showing  too many value to unpack

Comment: Can you give the url from where you are fetching? It would be easier to understand then.

Comment: @Kalyan Ok try for last time. If it doesn't works, I'll delete this.

Answer (score 1):

`\` is escape character in json:

[image]

you can load json string to python dict:
[image]