# Python: Does regular expression match escape sequences?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am currently learning regular expression in Python, and I am confused by what regular expression really matches. For example, `'\\'` is actually `'\'`, so what if I need to match the `'\'` in string `'abc\\cde'`? `re.findall(r'\', '010\\aa')` doesn't work at all. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `re.findall(r'\\', '010\\aa')`

Comment: You can't have a trailing backslash in a raw string: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash

Comment: Pythex <http://pythex.org/> is a great way to try out regular expressions and see what works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Now I understand what's wrong with my code, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, `\` is one character you still need to escape in raw strings:

```
re.findall(r'\\', '010\\aa')
```

Note that `r'\\'` is a string of length two, containing *two* backslashes, not one, unlike `'\\'`. This is described at the bottom of https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html .

Comment: `len(r'\x07')` is 4 characters, so it is not equivalent to `'\a'`. I think the regular expression library is doing its own conversion so that this can match `'\a'`.

Comment: And Python refuses to remove escapes when it parses raw literals, which is dumb.

Answer (score 0):

You always need to escape the delimiter in strings.
Since languages need to parse an escaped delimiter,
this requires parsing the escape itself.

This is a fact of language source string parsing, even raw strings.

Examples:

```
' => r'\''
\' => r'\''
\\' => r'\\\''
```