# Concatenating strings in Python

Tags: python, string

How can I properly concatenate a variable inside an string in Python?

I am trying to pass `service` in `"Database Connections\\'service'.sde"` and `(r"C:\GIS\Maps\'.+service+.'.mxd")`

```
service ="Electric"
sde = "Database Connections\\'service'.sde"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Maps\'.+service+.'.mxd")
```

so the output looks like

```
sde = "Database Connections\\Electric.sde"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\GIS\Maps\Electric.mxd")
```

Comment: If your question was sufficiently answered, you can accept the most helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think a better way to do this is using `os.path.join`:

```
import os
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(os.path.join(*"C:\\GIS\\Maps\\".split('\\') 
                                                    + ["{}.mxd".format(service)]))
```

Also, note that your back-slashes need to be escaped.

Comment: Aren't you mixing methods?  Shouldn't you join each component, e.g. `os.path.join(*"C:\\GIS\\Maps\\".split('\\') + ["{}.mxd".format(service)]` Surely the `\\\` is specific to the operating system, and the point of os.path.join is to join making it OS agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

This is how Python's string concatenation works:

```
sde = "Database Connections\\" + service + ".sde"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\GIS\\Maps\\" + service + ".mxd")
```

Comment: Thanks Mr Geek but I am getting error on second line!

Comment: @MonaCoder You should escape the `\` and remove the `r`, check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative which bypasses the issue of [raw strings can't end with a single backslash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash):

```
r'C:\GIS\Maps\%s.mxd' % service
```

and

```
r'C:\GIS\Maps\{}.mxd'.format(service)
```

both work fine, dodging the issue with the string ending in a backslash.