# Python regex string escaping for re.sub replace argument?

Tags: python, regex, regexp-replace

Using `re` module it's possible to use escaping for the replace pattern. eg:

```py
def my_replace(string, src, dst):
    import re
    return re.sub(re.escape(src), dst, string)
```

While this works for the most-part, the `dst` string may include `"\\9"` for example.

This causes an issue:

- `\\1`, `\\2` ... etc in `dst`, literals will be interpreted as groups.
- using `re.escape(dst)` causes `.` to be changed to `\.`.

Is there a way to escape the destination without introducing redundant character escaping?

---

Example usage:

```
>>> my_replace("My Foo", "Foo", "Bar")
'My Bar'
```

So far, so good.

---

```
>>> my_replace("My Foo", "Foo", "Bar\\Baz")
...
re.error: bad escape \B at position 3
```

This tries to interpret `\B` as having a special meaning.

---

```
>>> my_replace("My Foo", "Foo", re.escape("Bar\\Baz"))
'My Bar\\Baz'
```

Works!

---

```
>>> my_replace("My Foo", "Foo", re.escape("Bar\\Baz."))
'My Bar\\Baz\\.'
```

The `.` gets escaped when we don't want that.

---

While in this case `str.replace` can be used, the question about destination string remains useful since there may be times we want to use other features of `re.sub` such as the ability to ignore case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue - could you give an example string, src, dst which demonstrates it?

Comment: Looks like what you really want is `src.replace(r'\', r'\\')` as you don't seem to want `.` be replaced.

Comment: @metatoaster Do you meant `dst` ? - if this avoids all possible interpretations, then yes.

Comment: @ideasman42 yes. If you only want just this character this would be a way.  If you want multiple modifications from this subset, using [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) may be more desirable. Best approach is to create a number of test cases (add them to your unit test module) to formalise the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @ideasman42 Did you get a solution to this without replacing the dst variable. In my case the capture groups are being treated as literals without the re.escape()

Comment: @metatoaster Your code does not work. Raw strings in Python cannot contain single backslash as the last character. The change of the line in the original function would be: `return re.sub(re.escape(src), dst.replace('\\', r'\\'), string)`

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong fair, though the demonstration of using `r'\'` was more an illustrative purpose.

Answer (score 5):

In this case only the back-slash is interpreted as a special character, so instead of `re.escape`, you can use a simple replacement on in destination argument.

```py
def my_replace(string, src, dst):
    import re
    return re.sub(re.escape(src), dst.replace("\\", "\\\\"), string)
```

Comment: Raw strings in Python cannot contain single backslash as the last character. The modified argument would be: `dst.replace("\\", r"\\")` or maybe less confusingly without combining normal and raw strings: `dst.replace("\\", "\\\\")`

Comment: `r"\\" == "\\\\"` is true here for Python 3.10.

Comment: That just supports the second variant in my comment and it should be true in all supported versions. --- I was notifying you about something completely different: *You cannot have a **single (precisely: unpaired)** backslash as the last character of a raw string.* (Paired are fine.) This fails also in Python 3.10 (which started to take advantage of the new PEG parser) --- `>>> sys.version` `'3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]'` `>>> r"\"` ... `SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 1)`

Comment: Good explanation: [Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654184/320437)

Comment: Ah `r"\"` does indeed fail, thanks - updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, if you would just remove that `re.escape`, which I'm not sure why we would have that:

#### Test 1

```
import re 

def my_replace(src, dst, string):
    return re.sub(src, dst, string)


string = 'abbbbbb'
src = r'(ab)b+'
dst = r'\1z'

print(my_replace(src, dst, string))
```

#### Output 1

```
abz
```

#### Test 2

```
import re


def my_replace(src, dst, string):
    return re.sub(src, dst, string)


string = re.escape("abbbbbbBar\\Baz")
src = r'(ab)b+'
dst = r'\1z'

print(my_replace(src, dst, string))
```

#### Output 2

```
abzBar\Baz
```

#### Test 3

```
import re


def my_replace(src, dst, string):
    return re.sub(src, dst, string)


string = re.escape("abbbbbbBar\\Baz")
src = r'(ab)b+'
dst = r'\1' + re.escape('\\z')

print(my_replace(src, dst, string))
```

#### Output 3

```
ab\zBar\\Baz
```

#### Test 4

To construct the `dst`, we have to first know if we'd be replacing our string with any capturing groups such as `\1` in this case. We cannot `re.escape` `\1`, otherwise we would replace our string with `\\1`, we have to construct the replacement, if there are capturing groups, then append it to any other part that requires re.escaping.

```
import re


def my_replace(src, dst, string):
    return re.sub(src, dst, string)


string = re.escape("abbbbbbBar\\Baz")
src = r'(ab)b+'
dst = r'\1' + re.escape('\9z')

print(my_replace(src, dst, string))
```

#### Output 4

```
ab\9zBar\\Baz
```

Comment: Escape is needed because I don't have control over the arguments. they may contain special characters which need to be interpreted as literals.

Comment: Test 2, is interpreting the destination, try: `dst = r'\9z'`

Answer (score 0):

You could resort to split:

```
haystack = r"some text with stu\ff to replace"
needle = r"stu\ff"
replacement = r"foo.bar"

result = replacement.join(re.split(re.escape(needle), haystack))
print(result)
```

This should also work with needle at the beginning or end of haystack.