# EOL while scanning string literal even using r

Tags: python

I am trying to define a name for a long server folder path below.  May I know why I still get "EOL while scanning string literal" error?  Many thanks.

```
path= (r '\\hbap.adroot.abb\HK\Finance\00210602\AMH_A2R\1KY\Drv Reengine\Python\')
```

Comment: does it work if you use forward slashes instead? what about doubling the backslashes like \\

Comment: oh, i just saw the edit, you have a space between the r and the string

Comment: You have a space between `r` and `'`.

Comment: Did you copy and paste your code? You should be getting a syntax error because of the space between r and '. If you did not copy paste your code, please do so.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash

Comment: @StijnDePauw If you think this question has an answer somewhere else in this site - [flag it as duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) instead of posting a link as a comment...

Answer (score -1):

Its not allowed to put a space between the 'r' and the string. However i suggest just doubling the backslashes to escape them like this:

```
path= ("\\\\hbap.adroot.abb\\HK\\Finance\\00210602\\AMH_A2R\\1KY\\Drv Reengine\\Python\\")
```

Alternativly, you can just leave out the backslash at the end and do this:

```
path= (r"\\hbap.adroot.abb\HK\Finance\00210602\AMH_A2R\1KY\Drv Reengine\Python")
```

All is good, as long as you escape the backslashes and dont have the string ending with a \ (except if that ending backslash is doubled)

Comment: Oh thanks, didnt notice that

Comment: Why would you suggest doubling the slashes if they can be reduced by using a raw string? I'm just curious