# Python ignores escape sequences

Tags: python, printing, escaping

Lets say that i have function **load_from_xml()** which loads string from XML file. String contains escape sequences for example:  `"Here\x20are\x20spaces"`. When i want to print it I get:

```
s = str(load_from_xml())
print(s)
>"Here\x20are\x20spaces"
```

which is not desired output.
Desired output would be:

```
>"Here are spaces"
```

Any idea why print() ignores escape sequences?

Edit:
Sample of function of load_from_xml():

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def load_from_xml():

    xml_string = "<data>Here\\x20are\\x20spaces</data>"  # double \\ so data are stored like \x20 
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_string)
    return root.text
```

Comment: Could you add an example for your 'load_from_xml()' function? I ran the program using your example string and I had no problems.

Comment: Just found out simmilar question and answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4020539/process-escape-sequences-in-a-string-in-python/4020824#4020824)

Comment: `print()` isn't "ignoring" escape sequences; `print` is *not responsible for them in the first place*. Unless you explicitly use code to simulate the effect, escape sequences **only** apply to string *literals, in the source code of your program*, and their effect is applied *before the code runs*.

Answer (score -1):

It's **unquote** you're looking for :)

```py
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote("Here\x20are\x20spaces")
```

EDIT :

Then, simply :

```py
import urllib
urllib.parse.unquote(load_from_xml().replace(r'\\', r'\'))
```

EDIT :

But no, actually, the simple first solution I gave you will work, looking at your function, you already have simple slashes in your example...

And to answer to your final question :
Because it's not a usual escape sequence, it's an url quoting sequence...

Comment: This might work but string that I am getting as input should be written more like "Here\\x20are\\x20spaces" so that the escape sequence is written as string not like unicode char.

Comment: This answer is **completely wrong**. "And to answer to your final question : Because it's not a usual escape sequence, it's an url quoting sequence..." No, the escape sequence in question is not specific to URLs at all. The point is that the string **actually contains** a backslash, lowercase x, two and zero. The code here will not work and makes no sense. `"Here\x20are\x20spaces"` *in the source code* **already** contains spaces, so `urllib.parse.unquote` does nothing; `r'\'` [is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/) and trying this kind of replacement makes no sense anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
a="Here\x20are\x20spaces"
"".join(c for c in a if  c.isprintable())
```

Output:

`'Here are spaces`'

[str.isprintable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isprintable)

> Return True if all characters in the string are printable or the
> string is empty, False otherwise. Nonprintable characters are those
> characters defined in the Unicode character database as “Other” or
> “Separator”, excepting the ASCII space (0x20) which is considered
> printable.

Comment: This might work but I am looking for something that can convert all escape sequences not just spaces.

Comment: This answer is wrong, and misses the point entirely. Writing `a="Here\x20are\x20spaces"` **in source code** creates a string that **already contains** perfectly ordinary spaces, so there is nothing to replace. `\x20` is a code **for a space**. The problem is that the input **does not** contain spaces; it contains *actual backslashes etc.* which need to be converted. Backslash is a printable character, so this would not filter anything out, and it shouldn't be filtered out anyway - it should be converted.