# Deal with last character of backslash in "r" prefix and "+" in Python

Tags: python, prefix

From [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-prefixes-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals), the **r** prefix is about *raw string*. Actually, there are some situations that cause me very difficult to understand the **r**'s function. Let me express my opinion:

1. `'H:\\Education'` equals `r'H:\Education'`, as **r** prefix means not convert characters. But, if tested in Python, `'H:\Education'` equals `'H:\\Education'`. What is the function of **r** here, `\` equal `\\` no matter there is **r** leading?
2. As `'H:\Education'` equals `'H:\\Education'`, `'H:\Education\'` should equal `'H:\\Education\\'` or `'H:\Education\\'` or `'H:\\Education\'`, but actually, these four are not the same in Python; Why? Is it about the location of `\` or `\\`?
3. If **r** does nothing in list **1**, why `r'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'` is right but `'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'` is not right?
4. `r'H:\Education\'` is wrong, why?

So, sometimes **r** has function, sometimes not. How can I tell them and make the right choice?

Comment: The part you're missing is that \x doesn't always have a meaning.  With r'...', backslashes are always backslashes.  Without the r, if the character after the `\ ` is a set of specific characters, then the \ and that character are treated as a single character.  Otherwise the \ is just a slash.  `'\\h'` is the same as `'\h'` because \h doesn't mean anything.  But \7 does.

Comment: You can sometimes get by with writing only a single backslash in a non-raw string literal, *IF* the following character does form a recognized escape sequence.  For example, `\E` currently has no meaning, so writing `'\E'` produces the same string as `'\\E'` or `r'\E'`.  However, this is dangerous to rely on, as a future version of Python might add new escape sequences, or declare that invalid escape sequences are an error.  Your third example fails because `\7` *is* a recognized escape sequence - it produces the character with octal value 7.

Comment: @jasonharper May you check the fourth condition in the question I modified?

Comment: For that specific case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647769/why-cant-pythons-raw-string-literals-end-with-a-single-backslash

Comment: You need to separate the VALUE of a string from the REPRESENTATION of that string.  The string that we write `"\rZ\n"` contains three characters, two of which are not printable.  It does not contain a backslash, nor does it contain the letter "r".  If you view that string in a Python command-line, it will print it as five characters.  If you `print` that string, you'll see only the letter Z and a blank line.  If we write that string as `r"\rZ\n"`, now the string contains 5 characters, all printable, including two backslashes and the letter "r".

Comment: Your 4th item is a syntax error, because even in a raw string, we need a way to include the quote character.  The `\'` sequence embeds an apostrophe in the string.  You need to add an additional apostrophe to close the string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The details are in the docs at [String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals). Pay particular attention to the *recognized escape sequences* table a few pages down. Here are some rules

1. `\\` is converted to `\`
2. `\ooo` (with o being octal digits) is converted to octal
3. unrecognized escape sequences are left in the
   string unchanged, i.e., the backslash is left in the result.
4. Even in an r literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the backslash remains in the result

In...

- `'H:\\Education'`, the double backslash is replaced with a single backslash by rule 1.
- `'H:\Education'`, the backslash stays in the string by rule 3.
- `'C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe'`, the `\7` is converted to an octal value by rule 2.
- `r'H:\Education\'` the final quote is escaped (meaning it is treated as part of the literal) but that means that the literal string itself is never terminated with a closing quote which is a parser error.

It's something of a dark art. The reason why people double-escape all backslashes in Windows paths is that it is easy to miss which things don't change because of rule 3 verses the multiple things that do change. Your `7z` issue is a classic case. Better to double escape everything that run the risk you missed one of the rules.

Answer (score 2):

The `r` prefix stops [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) from being interpreted. `\E` happens to not be an escape sequence, so `'\E' == r'\E'`, but `'\n'` is a newline character, for example. You should never rely on this behaviour just to save typing an extra backslash or an `r` prefix; it’s very fragile.

As for a backslash at the end of a string literal: for better or for worse*, prefixes like `r` and `f` don’t affect the grammar of a string literal, just its interpretation. That means that in a code snippet like `r'foo\'`, the `\` is still serving to escape the closing quote, and you need to write `r'foo' '\\'` to get the desired string, for example.

```
>>> print(r'foo\bar' '\\')
foo\bar\
```

* better: parsing becomes easier, and forwards-compatible with new prefixes. worse: this issue.

Comment: How do you know the backslash at the end of a string will be an escape sequence?