# Misunderstanding removing escape characters using r before ""?

Tags: python, escaping

I have a misunderstanding of the use of `r` in print function to remove escape characters. Very basic example of what is not working for me below and one of several efforts I have made to remedy the situation:

```
print(r"I am trying to keep the backslash in the link using r  \www.home.com\")

SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (detected at line 19)
```

This is the error that is presented to me when I try to print to console. I have attempted different ways to end the string literal. Can someone help me to understand what is happening here and the logic.

I have attempted various fixes like:

```
print("\\www.home.com\\")
```

This does work, but in my head using `r` before the `""` should work too.

```
Example of what works:
print(r"This string would print normally if I remove the last back slash \www.home.com")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I have a misunderstanding of the use of r in print function to remove escape characters. ..."*

This is called a *raw string*.

Here are some excerpts, from the *[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)*.

*[The Python Language Reference – 2.4.1. String and Bytes literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals)*

> "... Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a letter `'r'` or `'R'`; such strings are called *raw strings* and treat backslashes as literal characters. ..."

*[The Python Tutorial – 3.1.2. Text](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#text)*

> "... If you don’t want characters prefaced by `\` to be interpreted as special characters, you can use *raw strings* by adding an `r` before the first quote ...
>
> ... There is one subtle aspect to *raw strings*: a raw string may not end in an odd number of `\` characters; see the [FAQ entry](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-programming-raw-string-backslash) for more information and workarounds. ..."

The reason your code doesn't work is because *Python* is interpreting the *[escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence)* as a literal value.
The `\` is essentially capturing the subsequent character.
Thus, the ending `\"` is considered literal.

Here is a similar question and answer.
*[Why can't Python's raw string literals end with a single backslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/647769/17758716)*

In this case, just use a regular *string literal*.

```java
print("I am trying to keep the backslash in the link using r  \www.home.com\\")
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a special limitation of a raw string that a raw string cannot end with a backslash.

Excerpt from [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#escape-sequences) of the official documentation:

> Even in a raw literal, quotes can be escaped with a backslash, but the
> backslash remains in the result; for example, `r"\""` is a valid string
> literal consisting of two characters: a backslash and a double quote;
> `r"\"` is not a valid string literal (even a raw string cannot end in an
> odd number of backslashes). Specifically, a raw literal cannot end in
> a single backslash (since the backslash would escape the following
> quote character).

So in such a particular case where a string literal needs to end with a backslash but contains other backslashes, one workaround is to write the ending backslash as a separate string literal with the backslash escaped with another backslash:

```
print(r'C:\deeply\nested\folders' '\\')
```

and another workaround is to pad the last backslash with a space and then call the `rstrip` method to remove it at runtime:

```
print(r'C:\deeply\nested\folders\ '.rstrip())
```

both of which may arguably look cleaner than writing the entire string literal in regular quotes cluttered with escape sequences:

```
print('C:\\deeply\\nested\\folders\\')
```

All three approaches produce the same output of:

```
C:\deeply\nested\folders\
```

Comment: Sorry it took me a long time to respond.  Was not intentional. Thank you so much for your explanation and that makes a lot of sense.  I appreciate the time and help.